# How can I select different filterable attributes for different categories in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, layered-navigation

I would like to have **different filterable attributes** in **different categories** so that only the most relevant filters are displayed. I am using Magento 1.9

**Example:**

Category -> Price, Color
SubCategory -> Price, Color, Material, Manufacturer

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from admin.

- Navigate to Catalog->Manage Categories
- Click a category (or subcategory). Go to the Display Settings tab and you'll see different options.
- Tweak the "Exclude filtering options for attributes" multiselect till you get what you want.

Comment: Do you have an extension installed that provides this option? I'm using Magento CE 1.9.1 and don't see the 'Exclude filtering options...' in the Display Settings for categories.

Comment: Yes, our version is Enterprise and highly customised. Just checked and found out that wasn't available on vanilla community. I found a few links that may be helpful though [this](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) will help create a backend tool to manage category attributes, and [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/) will show how to write an upgrade script to do it.